# Node - Convert from base64 string to utf-8 byte code array

Tags: node.js, utf-8, base64

I'm currently trying to convert images from a base 64 string to a utf-8 byte code array.  Below is the code I'm attempting to use with the base 64 string replaced for clarity.  I'm getting what looks to be a utf-8 byte array, but have not been able to find a way to verify.  Any help with a resource to help verify or if the code is incorrect?

```
const b64 = '...base64 string';
// convert to utf8 string
const utf8 = (Buffer.from(b64, 'base64')).toString('utf8');
// create a buffer of utf8 string
const buff = Buffer.from(utf8, 'utf8');
// 
const arr = [...buff];
```

Comment: Try converting it back and displaying it?